# How to concatenate dataframes according to condition in a for loop?

Tags: python, pandas

I am iterating over files, process some data to generate arrays (Value1, Value2, Value3) and combine them into dataframes like these:

```
df1:
ID Country Value1 Value2 Value3
BB US      3.5    6.32   1.02   
BB US      6.7    2.32   5.2
BB US      9.3    4.32   4.02
BB US      4.6    5.32   4.1

df2:
ID Country Value1 Value2 Value3
BB AU      5.3    5.12   7.02   
BB AU      7.12   1.32   5.02
BB AU      3.542  2.12   2.02
BB AU      2.4    5.82   6.02

df3:
ID Country Value1 Value2 Value3
BB AU      0.23   1.23   9.1   
BB AU      4.567  4.46   9.2
BB AU      5.34   9.23   0.1
BB AU      9.67   6.34   2.14
```

All are of the same dimensions, with categorical columns (ID, Country). I want to concatenate the dataframes into a single dataframe at the end of the loop, but in cases where the categorial columns are identical (df2 and df3 in this example), I would like to only keep the dataframe with the highest value in column 'Value3' (df3 here), to get something like this:

```
dfconcat:
ID Country Value1 Value2 Value3
BB US      3.5    6.32   1.02   
BB US      6.7    2.32   5.2
BB US      9.3    4.32   4.02
BB US      4.6    5.32   4.1
BB AU      0.23   1.23   9.1   
BB AU      4.567  4.46   9.2
BB AU      5.34   9.23   0.1
BB AU      9.67   6.34   2.14
```

I know how to concatenate the dataframes, I think the rest could be done with `np.where` and `.apply` but can't figure it out.

Comment: create a list and `pd.concat()` , then groupby ID and Country and take max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
L = [df1, df2, df3]

df = pd.concat([x.assign(max1 = x['Value3'].max()) for x in L])
df = df[df.groupby(['ID','Country'])['max1'].transform('max').eq(df['max1'])]

print (df)
   ID Country  Value1  Value2  Value3  max1
0  BB      US   3.500    6.32    1.02   5.2
1  BB      US   6.700    2.32    5.20   5.2
2  BB      US   9.300    4.32    4.02   5.2
3  BB      US   4.600    5.32    4.10   5.2
0  BB      AU   0.230    1.23    9.10   9.2
1  BB      AU   4.567    4.46    9.20   9.2
2  BB      AU   5.340    9.23    0.10   9.2
3  BB      AU   9.670    6.34    2.14   9.2
```

Comment: Thanks, but this seems to actually return the .min(). I guess it gives the .max() if I use .min() instead or I'm missing something?

Comment: `but in cases where the categorial columns are identical (df2 and df3 in this example), I would like to only keep the dataframe with the highest value in column 'Value3' (df3 here), to get something like this:` It seems outpu tis not like it, can you explain more? My solution return max values of all columns if same categoricals

Comment: Yes. When `ID` and `Country` columns are identical between dataframes (like with `df2` and `df3`), I would like the selection to be based on the max value in column `Value3`. In this case, the max is `9.2` in `df3` and `7.02` in `df2`, so `df3` should be kept and `df2`  should be dropped.

Comment: @ocns - I understand now.

Comment: @ocns - Can you test now?

Comment: This seems to do the trick! Many thanks for your help (I did not now 'df.eq', useful)